# SSRS Custom Page Names

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

**How do you custom name only the last page in a report?** in a way where it overrides any page names already generated from any groupings.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do this.
The easiest is if you can change the last group name in your dataset to be whatever you want. However, I guess this is might not be suitable.

The second way

There are a few assumptions here as you have given almost no information in your question.

- Assumes your group is sorting alphabetically.
- Let's assume your groups are department names.

  - Accounts
  - Client Service
  - Sales
  - Warehouse

Your page name expression would be something like

```
=IIF(Fields!GroupColumn.Value = MAX(Fields!GroupColumn.Value, "myDataSet"), "The Last Page", Fields!GroupColumn.Value)
```

Basically we are just checking to see if the group name is the same as the last (Maximum)  group name in the entire dataset, if so, use a literal value, if not just use the group name.

Comment: Well the grouping from all previous content was automatically naming the last page when exporting even though the last page's content wasn't in a group, but I guess adding the last page's content into it's own new group and then going from there would solve the problem.